# HITS centrality

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want the centrality measure of a particular vertex in my graph, and for Closeness, Betweenness and Degree centralities I have been using :

```
Pick[bc, VertexList[graph1], 1 ]
```

However, for [`HITSCentrality`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HITSCentrality.html), the result is in two lists, and I'm not sure how to pick out the two values for a single node.

Something like this isn't working...

```
Pick[bc, VertexList[graph1], {1,1} ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `HITSCentrality` you could try

```
Pick[Transpose[HITSCentrality[graph1]], VertexList[graph1], 1]
```